# Tracking the changes in data of azure blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Azure provides tracking of activities by activity log but I am working on a use case in which I have to track changes in a JSON file that is in the Azure blob storage and I have to figure out how can I track changes in the file.

Comment: You can get notified when blobs are created, deleted etc. by using the event grid, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-overview). Is that good enough?

Comment: Thanks, @PeterBons but I need the changes as well in the blob

Comment: Then you can use [versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/versioning-overview) as well and manually download the current en previous version and calculate the differences. The event grid events can help to trigger that process.

Answer (score 0):

**You can enable Blob storage versioning to automatically keep track changes of a file in blob.When blob versioning is enabled, you can access earlier versions of a blob to recover your data if it is modified or deleted.**

> Each blob version is identified by a unique version ID. The value of
> the version ID is the timestamp at which the blob was updated. The
> version ID is assigned at the time that the version is created.
>
> When you call a write operation to create or modify a blob, Azure
> Storage returns the x-ms-version-id header in the response. This
> header contains the version ID for the current version of the blob
> that was created by the write operation.
>
> The version ID remains the same for the lifetime of the version.

***Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/versioning-overview***